# How to change default schema of LocalDateTime in Swagger documentation using springdoc?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, springdoc

We use Spring Boot and https://springdoc.org/ to generate OpenApi documentation. We want to change default schema for LocalDateTime, so we don't have the same annotation every time LocalDateTime is used. So, I added:

```java
    static { 
        SpringDocUtils.getConfig().replaceWithSchema(LocalDateTime.class, 
                new StringSchema().example("2021-07-05T10:35:17.000").pattern("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}[.]\\d{3}")); 
    }
```

it worked. The issue is that now it's impossible to add custom description or example for specific field:

```java
    @Schema(description = "important date") 
    private LocalDateTime aDate;
```

As you can see below description is missing in Swagger-UI:
[screenshot with missing description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSQEn.jpg)

Is it possible to fix? Is there another way to have default custom schema for LocalDateTime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use OpenAPICustomerCustomiser

```
@Bean
public OpenApiCustomiser openAPICustomiser() {​​​​​​​​​
    return openApi -> {​​​​​​​​​
        openApi.getComponents().getSchemas().forEach((s, schema) -> {​​​​​​​​​
            Map<String, Schema> properties = schema.getProperties();
            if (properties == null) {​​​​​​​​​
                properties = Map.of();
            }​​​​​​​​​
            for (String propertyName : properties.keySet()) {​​​​​​​​​
                Schema propertySchema = properties.get(propertyName);
                if (propertySchema instanceof DateTimeSchema) {​​​​​​​​​
                    properties.replace(propertyName, new StringSchema()
                            .example("2021-07-05T10:35:17.000")
                            .pattern("^\\d{​​​​​​​​​4}​​​​​​​​​-\\d{​​​​​​​​​2}​​​​​​​​​-\\d{​​​​​​​​​2}​​​​​​​​​T\\d{​​​​​​​​​2}​​​​​​​​​:\\d{​​​​​​​​​2}​​​​​​​​​:\\d{​​​​​​​​​2}​​​​​​​​​[.]\\d{​​​​​​​​​3}​​​​​​​​​$")
                            //copies original description
                            .description(propertySchema.getDescription()));
                }​​​​​​​​​
            }​​​​​​​​​
        }​​​​​​​​​);
    }​​​​​​​​​;
}​​​​​​​​​
```